# Nexus 7 Kitkat update showing Verification Failed error

Tags: updates, nexus-7, ota-update, 4.4-kitkat

When I tried to update Nexus 7 to Kitkat from Settings > About > Update, it downloads the Kitkat update and after that shows "verification failed". I bought Nexus 7 from US and now I am in India.

Comment: Are you rooted? If so, have you changed any system files? Does the error give any more information, usually it will state which file it has failed verification on.

Comment: @bmdixon Not rooted

Comment: I had the same problem on my Nexus 4 - I got the "Verification Failed" message twice, and on the third try it worked.